# serve images with relative path inside js files in django

Tags: django

**Background:**

my setting.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets/css','/var/www/mongo_conprima/static_files/css/'),
    ('assets/js','/var/www/mongo_conprima/static_files/js/') )
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

I am able to server static file in template this way

```
<script src="{% static "assets/SlickGrid-master/lib/firebugx.js" %}"></script>
```

**Problem:**
there are images inside my js files with relative paths which fail to load like this

```
/var/www/mongo_conprima/static_files/SlickGrid-master/slick.formatters.js:
   55  
   56    function CheckmarkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
   57:     return value ? "<img src='/images/tick.png'>" : "";
   58    }
   59  })(jQuery);
```

**ERROR:**
I get following errors in console

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/tick.png 404 (NOT FOUND) slick.grid.js:2567
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use global variable in your template and use it in your js files

**Template:**

```
<html>
<script>
   var GLOBAL_PATH = '{{ STATIC_PATH }}'; 
</script>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
return value ? "<img src='" + GLOBAL_PATH + "/tick.png'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static tag inside your function as well, so the javascript should look like

```
function CheckmarkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return value ? "<img src='{% static "/images/tick.png" %}'>" : "";
}
```

The static tag will give you full the path to static file.

Comment: I can not go on changing the urls in all js files

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions to this issue have been answered in the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574670/2487431

You can either add a config to the webserver that will invisibly redirect the paths to the correct static path or you can use the urls.py to add the redirect.

The link explains in depth how you can do this. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.